# Javascript, check for identical characters

Tags: javascript, validation, loops, for-loop, character

I got to make a script for checking an input box (password) for the same characters occuring twice. This should be used alongside with regex validation (that's already fully working).
To succeed I know that I need to use a (for?) loop somehow, that checks if one character appear twice.  Now this is a kind of odd thing to ask for. I know. But I'm not entirely sure about the conditions for the function. If anyone have any suggestions around how this could be made, that would be great.  An example: "ABad12" - will pass, whilst "AbAc12" will return false.  Thanks in advance.

```
function checkForm(form)


{

 var re = /^\w{6,10}$/;

  if(!re.test(form.pwd1.value)) {
  alert("Error: Password has to be in-between 6-10 characters!");
  form.inputfield.focus();
  return false;
  }


}
```

Above goes an example of what script I'd like to combine it with (among with more regex validations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how I would do this:

```
var str = "ABad12",
    valid = str.split("").filter(function(e, i, a) {
        return a.indexOf(e) !== i;
    }).length === 0;

if (!valid) {
    // ...
}
```

But note that array [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method is not available in old browsers, so check [browser compatibility page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Compatibility) in advance.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, had to think a little. But if using this code, it could load a function if valid, right? If I want this to work together with my current Regex for upper-, lower- and numerical characters. Could I trigger this function when all the conditions" has been validated? I suppose this needs to be a little rewritten to work with my current code. I'm still a beginner so it's pretty hard to visualize the end result for me.

Comment: @Holmberg It is always good to include your code in the question body, so that we can give you more precise solution.

Comment: I realized that from your answer, so I've done it now, I think that is sufficient, but I could include more if necessary.

Comment: I'm sorry for being such a pain, but as far as I understand you get one notification, no matter if you input too few characters, as my regex were for, or if you input two identical characters - either way you will get that same alert. However if I want both conditions to generate their own alerts, and still have them both working as they should. How could that be done? Or could I use the code that you showed, just that I keep the regexes apart from it?

Comment: @Holmberg I'm sorry, I don't know Swedish, so I was unable to identify if we could unite both checks under a single alert :) Just split them into separate `if` and it should work as you wish. My try in Swedish: http://jsfiddle.net/4mCAk/1/ :)

Comment: Haha, Ye I saw that first after I posted! Guess you was faster to obtain the code than me to edit. It looks just about right, except for the Swedish of course :). However it was a nice try! Thanks a lot for taking your time, I'm gonna try this out now.

Answer (score 0):

you do not need a for loop.
a simple regex is enough:

```
(\w)\1+


var validateRegEx=/(\w)\1+/;
validateRegEx.test("aa") -> return true;
validateRegEx.test("ab") -> return false;
```

Comment: This works only for characters that go one after another, which is not the only case here.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s simple (though a bit brute-force) code, pure JavaScript with no regexp:

```
function check(s) {
  var i;
  for(i = 0; i < s.length - 1; i++) {
    if(s.indexOf(s.substring(i,i+1), i+1) >= 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

It simply processes the string from the start and checks for each character whether that character appears later in the string.

If you integrate this into your code, you could issue a specific message. Before `return false`, you could call an error reporting function asking it to show e.g. `'Error: character “' + s.charAt(i) + '” appears more than once.'`